# Can I always get the generators of a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's say I have a group with a presentation in generators and relations:

$$G = \langle g_1, g_2, ...\mid r_1, r_2, ...\rangle$$

And I have $H$ a subgroup of $G$. If I take $h_1, h_2, ...$ the generators that are elements of $H$ and $q_1, q_2, ...$ the relations which relate only to the $h_i$. Can I say that:

$$H = \langle h_1, h_2, ... \mid q_1, q_2, ... \rangle$$

---

If that's not true, can I go in the other direction? In other words, can I say that if:

$$H = \langle h_1, h_2, ... \mid q_1, q_2, ... \rangle$$

then I can "extend" this to a presentation for $G$:

$$G = \langle g_1, g_2, ...\mid r_1, r_2, ...\rangle$$

such that each $h_i$ is one of the $g_i$ and each $q_i$ is one of the $r_i$?

Comment: You can extend it, because every relation in $H$ is some in $G$, so take simply a presentation of $G$ and add the generators and relations from $H$. The other direction is not true.

Comment: For the first direction, it might happen that no generators $g_i$ is an element of $H$, for example

Comment: @psl2Z nice, good call. Some of the generators and relations may be "redundant" but that's not a problem, right?

Comment: @Sora interesting. Is there a simple example? Actually, now that you say this, I guess $\mathbb{R}^2$ under addition could have all the horizontal and vertical vectors as generators but the sub-group of all the points where $x = y$ would not contain any of these, right?

Comment: Take $G=\langle x,y\mid\rangle$ (free group on two generators), and $H$ the subgroup generated by $x^2$.

Comment: That's a *presentation*, not a representation.

Comment: Fair enough, fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a small counterexample for your first question.
$G = \langle g,h \mid g^4, g^2h^{-1} \rangle.$

Then $G$ is cyclic of order $4$ and the subgroup $H = \langle h \rangle$ has order $2$, but none of the relators of $G$ involve only generators of $H$.